# Apex Rest service consumes API?

Tags: apex, governorlimits, limits, apexrest, rest-service

When consuming a salesforce apex Rest api, the header is not returned: Sforce-Limit-Info.

My question is, when I consume a personalized service, I am not consuming api?
What I noticed was when using standard services (services that have vxx.xx) the header is returned.

Comment: Are you asking if calls made to a custom apex rest webservice count against the max number of API calls in a 24h period?

Comment: yes. Calls to a custom service do not return the header Sforce-Limit-Info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST calls to Apex methods exposed via @RestResource to **do** count towards the 24 hour rolling API limit. Even if they don't include the `Sforce-Limit-Info` [Limit Info Header](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/headers_api_usage.htm).

It is implied, but not explicitly stated in the documentation based on what I've found so far.

Use the [Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm) resource to monitor the usage over time, or [one one the other methods to track API calls](http://www.fishofprey.com/2016/06/monitoring-your-salesforce-api-usage.html).